# what does model.output.op does in keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

This is part of the code of grad-cam:

```
def generate_grad_cam(img_tensor, model, class_index, activation_layer):
    inp = model.input
    y_c = model.output.op.inputs[0][0, class_index]
    A_k = model.get_layer(activation_layer).output
```

What does `model.output.op.inputs[0][0,class_index]` do? What is `model.output.op`?

[image]

In this picture which one is the 
model.output.op.inputs[0][0, class_index]??

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of exploring in the TF/Keras code, and based on that investigation I believe what

```
model.output.op
```

provides is the mathematical "operation" at the output layer of the model.  The *inputs* provide the list of input tensors to that operation (for example in your case inputs[0] is the first input to whatever the actual op is).  The remaining part is slicing into that tensor to extract a certain element.

After running this code for the VGG16 example model:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.keras.backend.clear_session()  # For easy reset of notebook state.

myNewModel = tf.keras.applications.VGG16()
print('myNewModel.output.op:')
print(myNewModel.output.op)
print('myNewModel.output.op.inputs[0]:')
print(myNewModel.output.op.inputs[0])
print('myNewModel.output.op.inputs[0][0,3]:')
print(myNewModel.output.op.inputs[0][0,3])
```

I get this output - Note that I used 3 for the class_index just for an example:

```
myNewModel.output.op:
name: "predictions/Softmax"
op: "Softmax"
input: "predictions/BiasAdd"
attr {
  key: "T"
  value {
    type: DT_FLOAT
  }
}

myNewModel.output.op.inputs[0]:
Tensor("predictions/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 1000), dtype=float32)
myNewModel.output.op.inputs[0][0,3]:
Tensor("strided_slice:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: model.output.op.inputs[0][0, class_index] waht about this code? can you give me the explain with example? like vgg?

Comment: I added some additional information using VGG16 to the answer.  I hope this helps.